# How to remove duplicate records from a MySql 5.5. Derived Table, which aggregates data by date

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, inner-join, derived-table

The following table called **hb_lead** stores a unique lead, code and timestamp. Let's call the events recorded here *reg*

```
 id_hb_lead | lead_code | creation_date
 -----------|-----------|--------------
  1         | ABC       | 2018-10-01
  2         | DEF       | 2018-10-02
  3         | GHI       | 2018-10-02
  4         | CYZ       | 2018-10-03
  5         | HIJ       | 2018-10-10
```

The **hb_lead_engagement** table stores many times each lead engages with some stuff.  Let's call the events registered here *enga*

```
 id_hb_lead_engagement | id_b_lead |  id_event | event_date
 ----------------------|-----------|-----------|----------- 
  1                    | 1         |       12  | 2018-10-02
  2                    | 2         |       12  | 2018-10-03
  3                    | 3         |       12  | 2018-10-03
  4                    | 4         |       12  | 2018-10-06
  5                    | 3         |       12  | 2018-10-08
  6                    | 5         |       12  | 2018-10-16
  7                    | 2         |       12  | 2018-10-19
  8                    | 3         |       12  | 2018-10-10
  9                    | 5         |       12  | 2018-10-10
```

I need to generate a table like this,  where for each and unique date,  the *reg* and *enga* events are counted.  Please don't care about 0 or *null*,  I can **COALESCE** with 0 or null ...

```
 date      |  reg     | enga
-----------|----------|-----------
2018-10-01 |    1     |    
2018-10-02 |    2     |    1
2018-10-03 |    1     |    2
2018-10-06 |          |    1 
2018-10-08 |          |    1
2018-10-10 |    1     |    2
2018-10-16 |          |    1
2018-10-19 |          |    1
```

Using a **Derived Table** which first **UNION** the two tables to list all event dates,  an then **COUNT** events,  I created a table like this,  which fails in duplicating dates when is the same date both *reg* and *enga* events are larger than 1.

```
 date      |  regs          | engas
-----------|----------------|-----------
2018-10-01 |    1           |    
2018-10-02 |    2           |    
2018-10-02 |                |    1
2018-10-03 |    1           |    
2018-10-03 |                |    2
2018-10-06 |                |    1 
2018-10-08 |                |    1
2018-10-10 |    1           |     
2018-10-10 |                |    2
2018-10-16 |                |    1
2018-10-19 |                |    1
```

So I know that the way to solve this,  say aggregate data for each row is to **JOIN** two tables mainly LEFT JOIN and then use **CASE**.  However due to the fact that this is a derived table,  it can be JOINED with itself,  so my question is How do I aggregate the resulting derived table,  knowing that derived tables can't be joined to itself.

If wondering how did I derived date, here is my query:

```
select *
from
(
  select   date_format(l.fecha_creacion, '%Y-%m-%d') as categoria, 
  count(*) as reg, '' as enga
  from hb.hb_lead l    
  group by  categoria

union 

 select  date_format(le.le_fecha_creacion, '%Y-%m-%d') fecha, '', 
 count(*) 
 from hb.hb_lead_engagement le
 where le.id_hb_evento = 12
 group by   fecha
 order by 1
) t1
```

I'm restricted to MySql version : 5.5.5-10.1.36-MariaDB,  so the **With a as ** is out of discussion.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `UNION` date column then use `outer join` base on it.

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.5)**

create table hb_lead (
   id_hb_lead int,
   lead_code varchar(50),
   creation_date date
); 



insert into hb_lead values (1,'ABC', '2018-10-01');
insert into hb_lead values (2,'DEF', '2018-10-02');
insert into hb_lead values (3,'GHI', '2018-10-02');
insert into hb_lead values (4,'CYZ', '2018-10-03');
insert into hb_lead values (5,'HIJ', '2018-10-10');


create table hb_lead_engagement (
   id_hb_lead_engagement int,
   id_b_lead int,
   id_event int,
  event_date date
);



insert into hb_lead_engagement values (1,1,12, '2018-10-02');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (2,2,12, '2018-10-03');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (3,3,12, '2018-10-03');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (4,4,12, '2018-10-06');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (5,3,12, '2018-10-08');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (6,5,12, '2018-10-16');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (7,2,12, '2018-10-19');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (8,3,12, '2018-10-10');
insert into hb_lead_engagement values (9,5,12, '2018-10-10');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select dt,
    COUNT(id_hb_lead) regs,
    COUNT(id_hb_lead_engagement) engas
from 
(
  select event_date dt from hb_lead_engagement
  UNION 
  SELECT creation_date FROM hb_lead  
) t1 
LEFT JOIN hb_lead_engagement bhle on t1.dt = bhle.event_date
LEFT JOIN hb_lead bhl on t1.dt = bhl.creation_date
GROUP BY dt;

| dt         | regs | engas |
| ---------- | ---- | ----- |
| 2018-10-01 | 1    | 0     |
| 2018-10-02 | 2    | 2     |
| 2018-10-03 | 2    | 2     |
| 2018-10-06 | 0    | 1     |
| 2018-10-08 | 0    | 1     |
| 2018-10-10 | 2    | 2     |
| 2018-10-16 | 0    | 1     |
| 2018-10-19 | 0    | 1     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pCx783NSm1HuF8X8b2BTLU/0)